# Database Design for Dynamic/Reusable Form Templates

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

I apologize for the poor title, I couldn't think of a more clear way to phrase what I need help with.

I'm working on an application that allows users to submit "reports" for when certain incidents happen in a workplace. These reports are basically just a form and they help gather information to help deal with any sort of claims such as insurance, medical bills, etc.

A report can be of different "report_types". For example, different report_types could be "Auto Accident" or "Employee Injury".

Within report_types, there can be different report_templates. For instance, a user could have an "Auto Accident Oregon" template or "Auto Accident California" template because the requirements to file an insurance claim may be different in different states. The same applies to all report_types, there can be different report_templates for each report type based on location or the information needed even though it is technically the same type of incident that occurred.

The report_template is basically just a name and a json object that defines the schema for how to render the form. When a user goes to submit a report, I use a form renderer library to render the report based on the schema in the report_template. Then when a user submits the report, I save the json data from the form in a report row.

Before the user submits a report, he has to check sign a box to say that the report is accurate, and I am storing that data on a report_signatures table.

I attached a picture of my current database design below, I would love some feedback on it to see if this makes sense for what I'm trying to accomplish. The other challenge I'm facing is to be able to have an audit log of the reports so every time a user updates a report and resigns the signature box, the versions will be track. I think an insert-only table on reports would work well here, but I would also love some help with gettin that to work.

[image: An overview of the database design I have so far]